# Closing All Positions on a Specific Time in cTrader

Tags: .net

is there any cAlgo expert? I am creating a simple cBot to close all active positions at a specific time. But it is not working. It is just not closing any positions and not getting any errors.

```js
using System;
using System.Linq;
using cAlgo.API;
using cAlgo.API.Indicators;
using cAlgo.API.Internals;
using cAlgo.Indicators;

namespace cAlgo
{
    [Robot(TimeZone = TimeZones.UTC, AccessRights = AccessRights.None)]
    public class CloseAllPositions : Robot
    {
        [Parameter(DefaultValue = 0.0)]
        public double Parameter { get; set; }

        protected override void OnTick()
        {
            if (DateTime.Now.Hour == 8 && DateTime.Now.Minute == 0)
                foreach (var position in Positions)
                {
                    ClosePosition(position);
                }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: This question seems to have nothing to do with JavaScript. Please remove the `javascript` tag or clarify your question to include relevant JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution:

```
if ( Server.Time.Hour == 0 )
{
    foreach (var position in Positions)
    ClosePosition(position);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Always use Server.TimeInUtc so that you are sure it's also working in Backtesting!

```
        if (Server.TimeInUtc.Hour == 8 && Server.TimeInUtc.Minute == 0)
            foreach (var position in Positions)
            {
                ClosePosition(position);
            }
```